# Returning to beginning of source data in excel

Tags: excel

Is there a formulaic way to return to the top of the source file once the reference cell has reached the end (not VBA)? For example:

```
     A      B
  1 001 63001210100
  2 001 63001210101
  3 001 63001210102
  4 001 63001210103    --end of source file 
  5 002                --should be 63001210100 again    
  6 002
  7 002
  8 002
```

I am basically pulling from another spreadsheet (the source file) and the data has reached the end. However, I need to repeat the data again from the beginning now that column A has changed. Column A is in text format by the way.

I know I can go to go to B5 and reference it to B1, but that makes things ugly because the source file may change in size. Is there a formula that can pull from the source data to the end, then return back to the beginning based on if a value in a different cell changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could come up with is using a combination of `INDEX`, `ROW` and `MOD` instead of `OFFSET`. This probably will perform better than my first answer.

```
=INDEX(A:A,MOD(ROW()-1,COUNTA(A:A))+1,0)
```

---

**First answer**

To do this with a formula, you could use a combination of `CountA`, `Offset`,  `Row` and `Mod`

This image shows an example of repeated values from the source in A1:A6

[image: repeating values]

The formula in B1 is

```
=MOD(ROW()-1,COUNTA(A:A))
```

It forms part of the function used in C1 (the part that offsets the row)

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MOD(ROW()-1,COUNTA(A:A)),0)
```

Comment: your first iteration lacks an 'f'

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a separate column with a counter (e.g. if your counter column is C, C1 would be 1, C2 would be 2 and so on)

Then you don't reference your source data by copying the whole column (e.g. `=Source!B1`, `Source!B2`,..., or whatever formula you are using now) but by using (`=INDIRECT("Source!B"&C1)`, `=INDIRECT("Source!B"&C2)`,...)

Indirect takes a cell reference as string and converts it to a correct excel reference. If you let your counter run from 1 to max_row_number, you will experience the exact same behaviour as you have now - the whole source column is copied.

But the twist is, that of course you can influence your counter value by a formula, like

(in C2) `= IF(A2<>A1,1,C1+1)`

This way the counter will start from 1 again every time the value of column A changes. Of course you can tweak this further.